# When to use Amazon Redshift spectrum over AWS Glue ETL to query on Amazon S3 data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

As AWS Glue ETL can be a python script, it can be used to perform SQL queries using database interfaces and the data can be loaded from Amazon S3 into a DynamicFrame. I am trying to understand when it is advantageous to use Amazon Redshift spectrum to query on S3 data.

Comment: When you want to reduce the storage cost and maintain the source data as is without undergoing any transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS Glue is used for gathering metadata (crawling) and for ETL. It is not for reporting or analytics. It can apply highly complex transformations (ideal for complex ETL requirement).

Redshift Spectrum is primarily used to produce reports and analysis against data stored in S3, usually combined with data stored on Redshift. However is CAN also be used for simple ETL. Much simpler to set up and use than Glue if you just need simple type ETL.

There is one other option that you do not mention, that is amazon Athena, this is a great tool to run queries directly against S3 data. It is similar to Redshift Spectrum but usually faster and cheaper, depending on your use case. It cannot combine S3 data with Redshift data.